# Website Uploading - Error "NaN" uploaded

Tags: php

I've been trying to setup a file hosting script, I've tried multiple scripts (7), and no matter what script I've used, I seem to always get the same error, and I've tried it on multiple devices, and on different HTTP(s) protocols...

(I've searched for a few days for a way to resolve this, but without finding a working solution...)

Uploading File: (Computer upload)
"Speed: NaN Bps. Remaining: NaN seconds | Progress: NaN% (NaN B / 2.45 KB)"

However, if I use something such as "Remote Upload" everything seems to work completely fine, any advice?

I've changed the php.ini file to max upload file size to 2048MB's (Just to test it)

I uploaded a simple gif, and it didn't seem to want to upload...

(Also the upload script was working completely fine before, then one day it simply stopped working...)

Apache2 Website Conf: [here](https://hastebin.com/doxezoxolu.apache)
(Hiding domain using example.net)

Comment: have you checked the error log? how big a file are you uploading, have you tried a very small file? php config is usually more relevant than apache.

Comment: Its pretty much self explanatory, you must be providing the wrong parameters, but there's not much anyone can help you with if you don't even provide a bit of the problematic code.

Comment: PHP by default save upload files in `c:\windows\temp`. perhaps the folder does not have write permission.

Comment: @Amir as you can see from the config, OP is not using windows... and I doubt `/tmp` wouldn't have write access

Comment: My php.ini: https://hastebin.com/icusidaxiw.scala
I've tried a 71.6kb file, a 4MB file, and a 400MB file (All fail once at 100% uploaded, and randomly sometimes)

Comment: @IndieGuts that does sound like folder config/permission issue. You'll need to verify you've configured target directory correctly and it has write permissions and free space.

Comment: oh also no apache2 errors

Comment: @eis there's ~400+ GB's of free space, I've setup chmod 777 to the /files/ directory, and have setup the www-data:www-data group permissions to the directory.

Comment: you could test enabling `;error_log = php_errors.log` and see if it gets messages

Comment: It wasn't giving any errors, the only errors that were being logged was from another part of the website that had nothing to do with the uploading, and it was fixed...
I've reinstalled the VPS and now I'm trying to reinstall the script, it's all the same code, however now I'm getting this error while installing:
"We could not detect UTF8 Encode/Decode support within PHP on your host. This is needed for the storage of secure account passwords. Your host can enable this via PHP." (Reminder: It's a VPS, and the php.ini encoding setting is UTF-8, Also using PHP-7.0)

Comment: Issue resolved, I reinstalled the VPS, I assume I broke a setting while tinkering while PHP, however, I couldn't seem to find what I could have broke. I checked php.ini, apache2 config, the site.conf inside sites-avaliable, however I couldn't get it to work.. resolved now though, thanks for helping!